# Do not add hashtag to URL when clicking link containg it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Some sites I've seen do this.

I have links like `<a href="#delete">Delete</a>`

Which then shows a div. This will of course add #delete to the end of the URL in the adress bar. Is there a way to still call #delete but not add it to the end of the URL?

For example GitHub, on some popups, you can see in the bottom left that the address is `https://github.com/settings/admin#delete_account_confirmation`

but when you press the link it does not add `#delete_account_confirmation` in the URL? But the popup still shows. How?

Comment: Please do share your code :)

Comment: You could prevent the default behaviour in the listener. `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: You can do it by removing your href and creating a method onClick

Comment: why do you use links and hashes, if you don't want these hashes to be used?

Answer (score 2):

Just call its click events `preventDefault()` method

```js
document.getElementById('preventAnchor').addEventListener('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var anchor = this.href.split('#')[1];
   document.body.scrollTop = document.getElementById(anchor).offsetTop; // Comment me out if you don't want scroll to occur
})
```

```css
div, a{
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
  width:100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#test" id="preventAnchor">Test</a>



<div id="test">test</div>
```

To answer the question of how the popup still shows - usually this would be achieved by using javascript to alter styles either by adding a class or altering it's style attribute directly. Sometimes they're also populated via AJAX before showing them or even dynamically created when the link is clicked. Sometimes it's a good idea to retain the anchor link so that someone can directly open the dialog box - think if you refresh the page or bookmarked it with the popup opened - you could have have your page check the anchor and take the user straight to that particular popup.

If you want to remove the hash but still navigate to the anchor you could use either `history.replaceState` without `preventDefault` which should work on most modern browsers or use `preventDefault` and set `document.body.scrollTop` as I have in the example above the latter solution will be more compatible with older browsers that don't support the history API.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent it from beeing opened as a link, something called `preventDefault` is being used:

```
$("a.popup").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   // Your code here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( '#a_id' ).click( function( e ) {
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( "#div_id" ).offset().top
    }, 1000);
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#div_id" id="a_id">click to go to div</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="div_id">this is div</div>
```

Check this can be any help.

Comment: @charlietfl removed stopPropagaton()

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#delete">Delete</a>
```

change to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a>
```

or

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```